# GTK# on Windows with Visual Studio 2010 - Can't build/debug (error)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gtk#

I've scoured the net for a solution but there isn't one. I'm trying to make applications in Visual Studio 2010 C# Express with GTK#. The application is extremely basic but it can not run because of an error. The error centers around glibsharpglue-2.

**Application**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Gtk;

namespace Ink
{
    class MainUI
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.Init();

            //Create the window
            Window mainWindow = new Window("Ink by InkPuppet");
            mainWindow.Resize(500, 600);

            //Create a label and insert text
            Label tempLabel = new Label();
            tempLabel.Text = "Hello World!";

            //Add label to form
            mainWindow.Add(tempLabel);

            mainWindow.ShowAll();

            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'Gtk.Application' threw an exception.
  Source=gtk-sharp
  TypeName=Gtk.Application
  StackTrace:
       at Gtk.Application.Init()
       at Ink.MainUI.Main() in C:\Users\Jared\Documents\DevelopmentProjects\Ink\Ink\MainUI.cs:line 13
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.DllNotFoundException
       HResult=-2146233052
       Message=Unable to load DLL 'glibsharpglue-2': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
       Source=glib-sharp
       TypeName=""
       StackTrace:
            at GLib.Thread.glibsharp_g_thread_supported()
            at GLib.Thread.get_Supported()
            at Gtk.Application..cctor()
       InnerException:
```

**I am referencing:**
- atk-sharp
- gdk-sharp
- glib-sharp
- gtk-sharp
- pango-sharp
- System
- System.Net

Please advise me on how to fix this, I just want to get developing but this nonsense prevents any productivity.

Comment: I think the problem is `Unable to load DLL 'glibsharpglue-2': The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: I don't know if you're joking... I'm well aware of what the problem is, what I need is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution; i added environment variables for mono (eg MONO_HOME D:\Mono with Path D:\Mono\bin) and then it worked. None of the guides said to do this..